# Postgres: is set_config(). current_setting() a private/robust stack for application variables?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

In my application I have triggers that need access to things like user id. I am storing that information with

```
set_config('PRIVATE.'|'user_id', '221', false)
```

then, while I am doing operations that modify the database, triggers may do:

```
user_id = current_setting('PRIVATE.user_id');
```

it seems to work great.  My database actions are mostly from python, psycopg2, once I get a connection I'll do the set_config() as my first operation, then go about my database business.  Is this practice a good one or could data leak from one session to another?  I was doing this sort of thing with the SD and GD variables in plpython, but that language proved too heavy for what I was trying to do so I had to shift to plpgsql.

Comment: As answered below, the data won't leak between connections. However, do be careful that most languages offer connection pooling, where a single underlying connection is actually reused for performance purposes. In this scenario data can leak between logical application connections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it's not really what they're designed for, you can use GUCs as session variables.

They can also be transaction scoped, with `SET LOCAL` or the `set_config` equivalent.

So long as you don't allow the user to run arbitrary SQL they're a reasonable choice, and session-local GUCs aren't shared with other sessions. They're not *designed* for secure session-local storage but they're handy places to stash things like an application's "current user" if you're not using `SET ROLE` or `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` for that.

Do be aware that the user can define them via environment variables if you let them run a `libpq` based client, e.g.

```
$ PGOPTIONS="-c myapp.user_id=fred" psql -c "SHOW myapp.user_id;"
 myapp.user_id 
---------------
 fred
(1 row)
```

Also, on older PostgreSQL versions you had to declare the namespace in `postgresql.conf` before you could use it.