# Does Postgres keep the current_setting the same throughout 1 transaction?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, row-level-security

What I need to know is if I can run into an issue where I have many transactions which start off by setting a current_setting var; can 1 transaction change the current_setting for another transaction?

What I cannot have happening is the current_setting var changing whilst a transaction is still taking place. So if Postgres processes each individual transaction sequentially I guess I'm safe.

I could not find a clear answer to this but hopefully there is some Postgres genius that can clarify this for me.

PS: Im using the current_setting for RLS and to authenticate application users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres: is set\_config(). current\_setting() a private/robust stack for application variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049205/postgres-is-set-config-current-setting-a-private-robust-stack-for-applicat)

Comment: (In particular, note that a setting may be transaction-scoped.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `current_setting` function in PostgreSQL returns the configuration parameter value for the current isolated session in which the transaction is running. The `current_setting` for one transaction cannot be modified by another transaction. With each transaction having its own unique session and settings, this separation ensures that using `current_setting` for purposes like Row-Level Security (RLS) and user authentication remains secure.